# Matplotlib not using dates from data

Tags: matplotlib

Still pretty new to data visulization and trying to do a simple graph to monitor my weight lose attempt. Matplotlib though seems to be doing something weird when plotting the dates and not sure how to specify for the graph to use my dates instead of trying to always start at the start of the month

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfOrg = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["2019-1-7", "2019-1-14", "2019-1-21","2019-1-28","2019-2-4","2019-2-11",
                          "2019-2-18", "2019-2-25", "2019-3-4"],
              "Weight:": [204.3,201,202.5,200.7,201.5,202.5,199.5,200.8,201.5]})
dfOrg["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfOrg['Date'])
maxDT = dfOrg["Date"].max()
missing = {}
missing["Date"] = pd.date_range(start=maxDT, end='2019-10-07', freq='7D',closed="right")
missing["Weight"] = []
for i in missing["Date"]:
    missing["Weight"].append(np.NaN)
missingDF = pd.DataFrame(missing)
df = pd.concat([dfOrg, missingDF], ignore_index=True)
df.drop(["Weight"], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={"Weight:": "Weight"}, inplace=True)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import datetime

formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%b %d') 
plt.plot(df["Date"], df["Weight"], color="g")
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.ylabel("LBS")
plt.title("Weight Loss Progress")
plt.axhline(linewidth=4, color='gold', y=170, label="Goal")
plt.ylim(160, 210)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1, 0.5], loc='center left')
plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

So ideally the graph should be showing my weight where the dates go from 2019-1-7 to 2019-10-07 which is my goal and a goal line. Instead when I see the graph it shows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
plt.xlim([plt.xlim()[0], datetime.date(2019, 10, 7)])
```

to adjust the x-axis range. This will give you

[image: Code output]

---

Edit - You can set the ticks to one per week on a specified weekday using

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=dates.MO))
```

Which will give you 
[image: By Weekday]

Comment: Is there no way to have it show the weeks on the x axis?